# Getting response headers with Java, encoding issue

Tags: java, http, encoding, response, webharvest

I am using Webharvest to download a file from a website and take its original name.

The Java code that I am working with is:

```
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.Header;
            import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient;
            import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpStatus;
            import org.apache.commons.httpclient.Header;
            import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.GetMethod; 

            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

            BufferedReader br = null;
            StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
            String attachName;

            GetMethod method = new GetMethod(attachmentLink.toString());

            int returnCode; 
            returnCode = client.executeMethod(method);
            Header[] headers = method.getResponseHeader("Content-Disposition");
            attachName = headers[0].getValue();
            attachName = new String(attachName.getBytes());
```

The result in webharvest is:

> attachment; filename="Resoluci�n sobre Mesas de Contrataci�n.pdf"

I cant make it take the letter

> ó

After I got the value of the header Content-Disposition into variable attachName, I also tried to decode it, but with no luck:

```
String attachNamef = URLEncoder.encode(attachName, "ISO-8859-1"); 
                      attachNamef = URLEncoder.decode(attachNamef, "UTF-8");
```

I was able to determine that the response charset is: ISO-8859-1

```
method.getResponseCharSet()
```

P.S. When I see the headers in Firefox Firebug - the value is ok:
Content-Disposition

> attachment; filename="Resolución sobre Mesas de Contratación.pdf"

Comment: Note that the response charset refers to the payload, not the header fields.

Also note that you seem to be using a very obsolete version of the HTTP components.

Finally, the server response is invalid; non-ASCII characters are not allowed here; see RFC 6266.

Answer (score 2):

Apache HttpClient doesn't support non-ascii characters in HTTP headers. [Taken from documentation](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/charencodings.html#HTTP_Headers):

> The headers of a HTTP request or response must be in US-ASCII format. It is not possible to use non US-ASCII characters in the header of a request or response. Generally this is not an issue however, because the HTTP headers are designed to facilite the transfer of data rather than to actually transfer the data itself.
>   One exception however are cookies. Since cookies are transfered as HTTP Headers they are confined to the US-ASCII character set. See the Cookie Guide for more information.